# IPv6: Is `::' equivalent to `0.0.0.0' when listening for connections?

Tags: sockets, ipv6

When I examine the output of [`IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcplisteners(v=vs.110).aspx), I see listeners on `0.0.0.0` as well as `::`.

I believe that listening on a port on `0.0.0.0` is equivalent to listening on a port on any network adapter,  at least my memory of the Windows socket API says that this is so.

It also makes sense to me that `::` would mean the equivalent in IPv6 parlance so a listener on `[::]:49156` would be listening to port `49156` on all IPv6 network adapters where as `[::1]:1434` would be port `1434` on only the IPv6 loopback adapter.

Is this correct?

I assume that IPv6 listen end-points only apply to IPv6 adapters. That is, if an adapter only had an IPv4 address, connections to it port `49156` would not be received by a listener on `[::]:49156`?

Also, has anyone noticed that the MSDN article for `GetActiveTcpListeners()` incorrectly declares that the returned objects "include listeners in all TCP states *except* the Listen state."?

Answer (score 35):

> I believe that listening on a port on `0.0.0.0` is equivalent to listening on a port on any network adapter, at least my memory of the Windows socket API says that this is so.

That is correct.  `0.0.0.0` is defined as `INADDR_ANY` and can be used to listen on all local IPv4 adapters.

> It also makes sense to me that `::` would mean the equivalent in IPv6 parlance so a listener on `:::49156` would be listening to port `49156` on all IPv6 network adapters where as `::1:1434` would be port 1434 on only the IPv6 loopback adapter.

From the perspective of listening, yes.  `::` is defined as `INADDR6_ANY` and can be used to listen on all local IPv6 adapters.  `::1` is defined as `INADDR6_LOOPBACK`.

> I assume that IPv6 listen end-points only apply to IPv6 adapters. That is, if an adapter only had an IPv4 address, connections to it port `49156` would not be received by a listener on `:::49156`?

That depends on the listener.  An IPv6-only listener cannot listen on an IPv4 adapter and cannot accept IPv4 clients.  However, a [dual-stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665.aspx) listener bound to `INADDR6_ANY` can bind to IPv4 and IPv6 adapters and accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients, where IPv4 addresses are reported by `accept()`, `WSAAccept()`, and `getpeername()` as [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5).

Comment: On Linux this is controlled by the setsockopt `IPV6_V6ONLY`, see the [ipv6(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ipv6) man page.

Comment: On Windows as well. See [IPPROTO_IPV6 Socket Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738574.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

While your wording is misleading and in so far wrong, I think you mean to say the right thing: the unspecified address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0` a.k.a. `::` means that the respective port isn't listening to a specific address, but to all of them - essentially the same what `0.0.0.0` in the IPv4 case says.

Answer (score 4):

The IPv6 address "::" is specifically unspecified, and is not a valid address, nor is it equivalent to the IPv4 address of "0.0.0.0".  See [RFC 3513, Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) Addressing Architecture, section 2.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513#section-2.5.2):

```
2.5.2 The Unspecified Address

The address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 is called the unspecified address.  It
must never be assigned to any node.  It indicates the absence of an
address.  One example of its use is in the Source Address field of
any IPv6 packets sent by an initializing host before it has learned
its own address.`

The unspecified address must not be used as the destination address
of IPv6 packets or in IPv6 Routing Headers.  An IPv6 packet with a
source address of unspecified must never be forwarded by an IPv6
router.
```

Comment: In IPv4, 0.0.0.0 is the "unspecified address" (RFC1122) with essentially the same meaning and purposeas "::" or "::0".

Comment: They're using "unspecified" in an ambiguous way.  Normally, in a standard, "unspecified" means "the standard does not address this".  Here, the standard *does* address it:  it specifically reserves it as a an address that must not be used for a node, and specifically notes that it might be used by a node that is trying to discover its own address.