# Redis: how to provide localhost / any address for ipv6?

Tags: redis

You can configure redis to listen on localhost only by providing in the redis.conf file

```
# Localhost
bind 127.0.0.1 
# All addresses
bind 0.0.0.0
```

How do the same for ipv6 addresses?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this with Redis, but the IPv6 localhost (loopback) equivalent is `::1` whereas the all zeros address (i.e.g. TCP's INADDR_ANY) equivalent is `::`.

Comment: What docs? This is all over the internets if you Google for IPv6 :) - do you you think the Redis docs (e.g. inline the redis.conf file) should include this info?

Comment: You see, IPv6 is a little different from IPv4. `0.0.0.0` was a valid IP address in IPv4. But its IPv6 equivalent `::` is [NOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480094/ipv6-is-equivalent-to-0-0-0-0-when-listening-for-connections) a valid address. So, I think such things SHOULD be documented, yes.

Comment: If it makes sense to you, perhaps it would make sense for others too - why not add it to the docs then?

Comment: I think I will do that on a weekend. Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Sounds like an amazing idea ;P